# Antes de ontem ou anteontem?

Tags: ortografia

Eu sempre usei *"antes de ontem"*, no entanto me deparei que algumas pessoas pronunciam anteontem, qual é o correto?

> anteontem

ou

> antes de ontem

Comment: Também existe a forma [*antontem*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/antontem) para dizer [“no dia que precedeu o dia de ontem”](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/anteontem), mas parece pouco utilizada.

Comment: @tchrist I don't see that. I see this on that page: anteontem
(
an·te·on·tem
)

advérbio
No dia que precedeu o dia de ontem. = ANTES DE ONTEM

etimologiaOrigem etimológica:ante- + ontem.

"anteontem", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/anteontem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Muitos usam *"antes de ontem"* no lugar de *"anteontem"*. No entanto, essas expressões não têm exatamente o mesmo sentido.

- **"Antes de ontem"** é mais genérica. De modo prático:

  Se hoje é quinta-feira e eu digo que um fato ocorreu antes de ontem, esse fato pode ter ocorrido terça-feira, segunda-feira, domingo, sábado, ou seja, qualquer dia antes de ontem.
- **"Anteontem"** (advérbio) é específica, refere-se apenas a um determinado dia. Por exemplo:

  Se hoje é quinta e eu digo que um fato ocorreu anteontem, esse fato ocorreu exatamente terça-feira.

Em resumo:

- *antes de ontem* - qualquer dia antes de ontem.
- *anteontem* - o dia anterior a ontem.

Fonte:

http://www.portuguesnarede.com/2013/08/questao-de-sentido-anteontem-x-antes-de.html

Comment: Na pratica, pelo menos na minha aplicação dessas duas expressões, não há diferença alguma, mas eu também não serei a pessoa mais indicada para fazer uma analise. Mas provavelmente esta distinção pode ser necessária em algumas situações, claramente.

Answer (score 15):

Ambas as formas estão corretas do ponto de vista linguístico. Contudo, quando nós queremos nos referir rigorosamente ao dia anterior a ontem, será preferível optar pelo advérbio de tempo, **anteontem**.

Isto porque a expressão **antes de ontem** pode não transmitir com precisão a ideia de **dia anterior a ontem**. O dia antes de ontem pode ser qualquer dia que já tenha se passado e não seja o dia de ontem.

Fonte: [Em Português Corre(c)to](http://emportuguescorrecto.blogs.sapo.pt/7812.html)

Comment: A expressão "antes de ontem" até é frequentemente usada para o dia anterior a ontem, ao contrário do que se consta aqui.

Comment: estou dizendo que é preferivel usar, não que é mais usado

Answer (score 0):

Anteontem traz referência ao dia anterior a ontem (se hoje é sexta, ontem foi quinta e anteontem foi quarta!), ou seja, não há extensão ou dubiedade do termo, devendo ser usado estritamente para se referir ao dia anterior a ontem... Antes de ontem, por sua vez, pode se referir a "qualquer" dia antes de ontem (se hoje é sexta, ontem foi quinta e antes de ontem podia ser quarta, terça, segunda ou qualquer dia anterior à esse, retroativamente). Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: O que tem de diferente das outras respostas? Faltou algo nas outras respostas?

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza as duas formas são corretas. A diferença está no significado, veja aqui:
http://qintelecto.blogspot.com.br/2016/11/dia-antes-de-ontem-ou-anteontem.html

Comment: Amigo isto não é fórum de suporte, é um Q&A, comentários deve ser feito no campo de comentários, agora se deseja que isto seja uma resposta dê contexto, note que isto não é uma opinião minha, mas sim uma característica do site como o Help explica http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer (leia a parte escrito **"Provide context for links"**), então por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: melhore a sua resposta que você ganha uns pontos positivos.